# Will distance to destination be received before navigationManager.simulate()

Tags: android, android-studio, here-api

I need to obtain the distance to destination(DTD) value even before route guidance is started for a particular destination.

For example:
Google maps provides distance to destination update and the time to reach the destination before even navigate option is chosen by the user

The scenario in my case is similar to this, but the distance to destination 
value is not being obtained unless below line of code is called:
navigationManager.simulate(route, 30);

Without simulating the route, the DTD value being returned is -0.0.
Similarly invalid values are being returned for ETA(Estimated time of arrival) and TTA(Time to arrive)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation on ETA of a route to be navigated (https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/index.html), a valid ETA is returned only when actively navigating a route.

> A valid ETA date is returned when actively navigating on a route (when the navigation mode is NAVIGATION or SIMULATION). Note that when a navigation event is being handled (for example, during a route recalculation), a NavigationManager.INVALID_ETA_DATE can be returned. A NavigationManager.INVALID_ETA_DATE will also be returned if not actively navigating on a route.

Comment: Is the same answer applicable for DTD(Distance to destination) and TTA(Time to arrive) values also. Is there any other way where i can get the values even before the route guidance is started ?